# How do I use System.IO.FileStream in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, stream

I'm a longtime Windows C# developer, trying to write an app in Xamarin.iOS.  I assumed System.IO functionality would be present and coded a file-writing class to use System.IO.FileStream.  It builds okay, but when I call FileStream.Write(bytes) (where bytes is a byte array), I get a NotImplementedException.

This document seems to imply that System.IO should be present and complete in Xamarin.iOS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system

What is going on?  Should the stream classes be available to Xamarin.iOS or not?  If so, how do I use them, and if not, what is the alternative?  NSStream, etc?

Comment: What overload of FileStream.Write are you using?

Comment: Aha, I think you're onto it.  I'm calling myFileStream.Write(bytes) where bytes is a byte array.  That appears to not be an actual method on the stream.  Maybe it's an extension method or...?

Comment: The debugger is telling me it's calling a method with this signature: Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source)

Comment: How about : `myFileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)` (Note: this is in a Xamarin.iOS project, are you doing this via PCL/NetStd lib?

Comment: Er, Visual Studio for Mac's Intellisense shows that signature.

Comment: Yeah, gimme a sec to try that.  I still have no idea where the overload I was using is coming from.

Comment: FYI: I know that `dotnet` (or I guess technically `coreclr`) has support in `mscorlib` for the new `Span` types, maybe you included some additional package in your project that is adding those `Span`-based extensions?